# ¿Por que no me encuentra mi archivo .js al ejecutar mi extension de chrome?

Tags: javascript, json

Generé los archivos para una macro y hacer la extension de chrome, pero al ejecutarla me aparece que no se encuentra el url o está modificado o dañado el archivo.

Adjunto mi codigo del archivo .js para ver si pueden identificar que estoy haciendo mal al llamarlo.

```
{
   "Name":"1.0",
   "CreationDate":"2022-3-9",
   "Commands":[
      {
         "Command":"open",
         "Target":"https://production.42-q.com/cognito/login.html",
         "Value":"",
         "Description":""
      },
      {
         "Command":"click",
         "Target":"id=username",
         "Value":"",
         "Targets":[
            "id=username",
            "xpath=//*[@id=\"username\"]",
            "xpath=//input[@id='username']",
            "xpath=//input",
            "css=#username"
         ],
         "Description":""
      },
      {
         "Command":"type",
         "Target":"id=username",
         "Value":"gdl3_production",
         "Targets":[
            "id=username",
            "xpath=//*[@id=\"username\"]",
            "xpath=//input[@id='username']",
            "xpath=//input",
            "css=#username"
         ],
         "Description":""
      },
      {
         "Command":"click",
         "Target":"id=submit",
         "Value":"",
         "Targets":[
            "id=submit",
            "xpath=//*[@id=\"submit\"]",
            "xpath=//button[@id='submit']",
            "xpath=//button",
            "css=#submit"
         ],
         "Description":""
      },
      {
         "Command":"click",
         "Target":"id=password",
         "Value":"",
         "Targets":[
            "id=password",
            "xpath=//*[@id=\"password\"]",
            "xpath=//input[@id='password']",
            "xpath=//input",
            "css=#password"
         ],
         "Description":""
      },
      {
         "Command":"type",
         "Target":"id=password",
         "Value":"",
         "Targets":[
            "id=password",
            "xpath=//*[@id=\"password\"]",
            "xpath=//input[@id='password']",
            "xpath=//input",
            "css=#password"
         ],
         "Description":""
      },
      {
         "Command":"click",
         "Target":"id=nextSubmit",
         "Value":"",
         "Targets":[
            "id=nextSubmit",
            "xpath=//*[@id=\"nextSubmit\"]",
            "xpath=//button[@id='nextSubmit']",
            "xpath=//button[2]",
            "css=#nextSubmit"
         ],
         "Description":""
      },
      {
         "Command":"click",
         "Target":"xpath=//*[@id=\"_145_myPlaces\"]/a/span",
         "Value":"",
         "Targets":[
            "xpath=//*[@id=\"_145_myPlaces\"]/a/span",
            "xpath=//a/span",
            "css=#_145_myPlaces > a > span"
         ],
         "Description":""
      },
      {
         "Command":"clickAndWait",
         "Target":"id=aui-3-2-0PR1-1572",
         "Value":"",
         "Targets":[
            "id=aui-3-2-0PR1-1572",
            "xpath=//*[@id=\"aui-3-2-0PR1-1572\"]",
            "xpath=//span[@id='aui-3-2-0PR1-1572']",
            "xpath=//li[5]/a/span",
            "css=#aui-3-2-0PR1-1572"
         ],
         "Description":""
      },
      {
         "Command":"clickAndWait",
         "Target":"linkText=Production Workbench",
         "Value":"",
         "Targets":[
            "linkText=Production Workbench",
            "id=sd5",
            "xpath=//*[@id=\"sd5\"]",
            "xpath=//a[@id='sd5']",
            "xpath=//div[4]/div/a",
            "css=#sd5"
         ],
         "Description":""
      },
      {
         "Command":"click",
         "Target":"xpath=//*[@id=\"pwb-container\"]/modal-login/ps-modal/div/div/div/div/div[2]/span[2]/i",
         "Value":"",
         "Targets":[
            "xpath=//*[@id=\"pwb-container\"]/modal-login/ps-modal/div/div/div/div/div[2]/span[2]/i",
            "xpath=//i",
            "css=#pwb-container > modal-login > ps-modal > div > div > div > div > div.ps-modal-header.ng-tns-c39-2.ng-star-inserted > span.ps-modal-header-icon.ng-tns-c39-2.ng-star-inserted > i"
         ],
         "Description":""
      },
      {
         "Command":"click",
         "Target":"xpath=//*[@id=\"icons-bar-bottom\"]/span[2]/i",
         "Value":"",
         "Targets":[
            "xpath=//*[@id=\"icons-bar-bottom\"]/span[2]/i",
            "xpath=//div[2]/span[2]/i",
            "css=#icons-bar-bottom > span:nth-child(2) > i"
         ],
         "Description":""
      },
      {
         "Command":"click",
         "Target":"id=conf-station",
         "Value":"",
         "Targets":[
            "id=conf-station",
            "xpath=//*[@id=\"conf-station\"]",
            "xpath=//input[@id='conf-station']",
            "xpath=//div[5]/ps-dropdown/div/div/input",
            "css=#conf-station"
         ],
         "Description":""
      },
      {
         "Command":"type",
         "Target":"id=conf-station",
         "Value":"ibpa",
         "Targets":[
            "id=conf-station",
            "xpath=//*[@id=\"conf-station\"]",
            "xpath=//input[@id='conf-station']",
            "xpath=//div[5]/ps-dropdown/div/div/input",
            "css=#conf-station"
         ],
         "Description":""
      },
      {
         "Command":"click",
         "Target":"xpath=//*[@id=\"aui-3-2-0PR1-1425\"]/div[2]/ul/li",
         "Value":"",
         "Targets":[
            "xpath=//*[@id=\"aui-3-2-0PR1-1425\"]/div[2]/ul/li",
            "xpath=//div[2]/ul/li",
            "css=#aui-3-2-0PR1-1425 > div.ps-autocomplete-panel.ng-star-inserted > ul > li.ng-star-inserted.ps-autocomplete-list-item.ps-state-highlight"
         ],
         "Description":""
      },
      {
         "Command":"click",
         "Target":"id=saveConfigurationsBtn",
         "Value":"",
         "Targets":[
            "id=saveConfigurationsBtn",
            "xpath=//*[@id=\"saveConfigurationsBtn\"]",
            "xpath=//button[@id='saveConfigurationsBtn']",
            "xpath=//div[2]/button",
            "css=#saveConfigurationsBtn"
         ],
         "Description":""
      },
      {
         "Command":"selectWindow",
         "Target":"title=Login",
         "Value":"",
         "Description":""
      },
      {
         "Command":"click",
         "Target":"id=username",
         "Value":"",
         "Targets":[
            "id=username",
            "xpath=//*[@id=\"username\"]",
            "xpath=//input[@id='username']",
            "xpath=//input",
            "css=#username"
         ],
         "Description":""
      },
      {
         "Command":"type",
         "Target":"id=username",
         "Value":"leonardo_montes",
         "Targets":[
            "id=username",
            "xpath=//*[@id=\"username\"]",
            "xpath=//input[@id='username']",
            "xpath=//input",
            "css=#username"
         ],
         "Description":""
      },
      {
         "Command":"click",
         "Target":"id=submit",
         "Value":"",
         "Targets":[
            "id=submit",
            "xpath=//*[@id=\"submit\"]",
            "xpath=//button[@id='submit']",
            "xpath=//button",
            "css=#submit"
         ],
         "Description":""
      },
      {
         "Command":"click",
         "Target":"id=password",
         "Value":"",
         "Targets":[
            "id=password",
            "xpath=//*[@id=\"password\"]",
            "xpath=//input[@id='password']",
            "xpath=//input",
            "css=#password"
         ],
         "Description":""
      },
      {
         "Command":"type",
         "Target":"id=password",
         "Value":"",
         "Targets":[
            "id=password",
            "xpath=//*[@id=\"password\"]",
            "xpath=//input[@id='password']",
            "xpath=//input",
            "css=#password"
         ],
         "Description":""
      },
      {
         "Command":"click",
         "Target":"id=nextSubmit",
         "Value":"",
         "Targets":[
            "id=nextSubmit",
            "xpath=//*[@id=\"nextSubmit\"]",
            "xpath=//button[@id='nextSubmit']",
            "xpath=//button[2]",
            "css=#nextSubmit"
         ],
         "Description":""
      }
   ]
}
```